# "Crit chance" word problem

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Normally, I can jump exactly 100cm into the air.  Sometimes, I can jump higher - by a predictable proportion and with a particular probability.  These higher jumps are "critical jumps."

- I have an attribute, "Dexterity" (DEX).  For each unit of DEX I possess, I can jump 2% as high on critical jumps as on normal jumps; or, my critical jump is (DEX/50)x the height of my regular jump.
- Currently, my DEX is 100, so that when I "critically jump," I jump 200cm high.  (To clarify: I can only jump either 100cm or 200cm into the air.)
- I also have an attribute, "Agility" (AGI), which dictates how often I can critically jump.
- Neither my DEX nor my AGI can be lower than 100.
- Currently, my AGI is 100, which is the baseline for AGI.  In other words, at AGI 100, I never critically jump.  At values above 100 AGI, I have an increasing chance to critically jump.
- My regular jump (Rj) height varies from day to day, but for my critical jumps (Cj), the DEX proportion (known: (DEX/50)(Rj)) and AGI frequency (unknown, but at AGI 100 = 0%) are the same.
- Depending on how I exercise, I can raise my DEX and AGI by arbitrary amounts, but for DEX=AGI and DEX>100 and AGI>100, my average jump (Aj) height will be [(AGI-100)*2]% higher than Rj -or- Aj = [((AGI*2)/100)-1]Rj

Q: *What % of jumps (Cf), as a function of AGI, would have to be critical jumps?*

My work before my brain bailed:
At 101 AGI and 101 DEX, if my regular jump is 100cm, my critical jump is 202cm; my average jump must be 102cm (1.96% or Cf=100/51?).  At 150 AGI and DEX, if my regular jump is 150cm, my critical jump is 450cm; my average jump must be 300cm (50% or Cf=(AGI-100)? AGI/3?).  At 200 AGI and DEX, if Rj is 50, then Cj is 200 and Aj is 150 (Cf=2AGI/3?)  At 500 each, if Rj=100, then Cj=1000 and Aj=900.    I believe that Aj = Cj - Rj as a rule.  It also seems right to calculate percentages as [((100-x)*Rj)+((x)*Cj)]/100 = Aj.  This is where I fall off.

The spirit of the question, for context/intent: I'm designing an RPG wherein each stat point spent offers a 1% increase in efficacy.  For example, strength directly multiplies outgoing damage (here, regular jump height) by 1% for every point above 100.  I couldn't, however, simply create a frequency that added a direct 1% for each point, or "critical hits" would happen for every hit at AGI=200, at which point it would not only make no sense to add points to AGI, but each point of DEX would add 2% to my efficacy overall; if I instead lowered DEX to a 1% increase in critical damage per point, DEX would only add a % of efficacy per point invested after AGI=200.  Instead, I decided to give AGI diminishing returns regarding a direct frequency, but linear returns assuming that points are spread evenly between DEX and AGI.  The idea is that if I put 100 points into strength to raise it to 200, I will hit for double damage in my regular attacks.  If I instead divided 100 points between DEX and AGI, I will do double damage on average between my critical and regular attacks.  Any insight, ideas, reformulations, links, or other are all appreciated in addition to a direct answer.

Comment: Hmmm; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket-propelled_grenade

Comment: Sure, I probably should have saved the preamble for the postamble. -.-  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-playing_game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer I was looking for:

Cf = (AGI-100)/(AGI-50)

or

((AGI-100)/(AGI-50))*100 % of jumps are critical jumps.

Now that I look back at my "work done so far" section, I had plotted this out so directly that it should have been obvious.

Comment: I don't know how to format math for graphical display.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think you're making everything hard on yourself by restricting yourself to linear scaling systems.  Having it so an equal number of points spread across stats is a problem tailor made for exponential scaling systems.

Consider a damage function like so:

$$D = e^{(d-d_0)/k_d} e^{(a-a_0)/k_a} D_0$$

where $d, a$ are dex and agility; $d_0, a_0$ are constants (like 100), and $k_d, k_a$ are just scaling constants so that the scaling is overall small.  If $k_d = k_a$, then 100 points in agility is *guaranteed* to be the same overall damage as 100 points in dexterity, or as 50/50 in each.

Another common failing of linear scaling systems is that stats diminish in relative worth as you stack them:  for instance, strength will keep adding only 1% of base damage per X points, but if you're already doing 200% normal damage, that 1% is worth half of what it used to be worth.  This is a classic example of the scaling mathematics driving stat decisions.  That can be fun for some people and players, but I would at least consider an alternative where *situations* drive stat decisions instead of math.  Exponential scaling systems do a much better job of getting out of the way.

Once you have the exponential scaling formula in place, you can build a correlation between it and a linear bonus factor that represents the damage done from crits.  In other words, you can equate

$$e^{(d-d_0)/k} e^{(a-a_0)/k} = 1 + bc$$

where $b$ is the crit bonus and $c$ is the crit chance.  Given that you've already stated you want $b = d/50-1$, a formula for $c$ shortly follows.  I'll roll in the constants so that 1 point of dex or agi increases capability by 2%:

$$c(a, d) = \frac{1.02^{d+a-200}-1}{d/50-1}$$

Of course, this crit chance formula is unbounded:  if $d = 100$, then just $a = 136$ gives over 100% crit chance.  I suggest this is more a problem with the crit bonus not increasing fast enough, rather than the crit chance being the issue, though.

---

We can do this approach for linear scaling instead:

$$D = (d/50-1)(a/50-1) D_0$$

That would give the following answer:

$$1 + (d/50-1)c = (d/50-1)(a/50-1) \implies c = \frac{a}{50} - 1 - \frac{1}{d/50-1}$$

But the key point about having dex and agi both give the same benefit is lost, I think.  50 points each in dex and agi will be far more effective than 100 points in either one.  This is one of the main drawbacks of linear scaling:  it forces people down a balanced stat path.  If that's what you want, good, but if you want to give the option, this math doesn't support it.

Comment: I can't vote up yet, but this is an excellent answer.  You gave me exactly the kind of ideas and directions I had hoped for!  Since I'm programming this, it's even very clearly written out in a way I can use.

Comment: However... some thoughts back.  First, the idea that the crit frequency never reaches 100% is crucial.  Second, I'm not getting the expected results from your bottom equation.  At DEX&AGI 100 or 150, it seems right, but take DEX 300 and AGI 300: I expect that if Rj is 100, Cj will be 600 (DEX/50 * Rj) and Aj should be 500.  By your formula, I got 2500 for Aj.  Certainly, Aj should never be higher than Cj, as that would mean that I have a higher than 100% critical frequency.

Comment: I'm not surprised; the derived formula has some strange properties.  For instance as $d$ increases, the crit chance actually $increases$ slowly.  At $a=300$, you get $c \geq 4$, or 400% critical chance.  What probably needs to happen is that the crit chance is capped (using some asymptotic function) by design.  Alternatively, you could have "critical crits".

Comment: With critical crits, however, it makes it even clearer that distributing the two stats evenly is far more advantageous.  What I was looking for was something like my formula for EHP (effective hit points) through mitigation.  For each point of toughness, I raise damage mitigation by ((-100+TGH)/TGH)*100%, thereby increasing "effective" hit points by 1% for each point.  The advantage is that mitigation of damage would never reach 100%.  I was looking for the same formula for AGI and crit chance, with the given that DEX will raise the crit hit amount.